# Passing a UIImage from a viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I want to pass a UIImage from a View Controller to another one, but it doesn't work. I actually get (null) if I log the UIImage Value in the second View Controller.

The Image File comes from parse.com. And it works absolutely fine in the first view controller. But as soon as I pass it to the second view controller, the image won't work there.

Here's the code:

My prepareForSegue in the .m file of the firstViewController (BookListTableViewController)

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowBookDetailSegue"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.bookListTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ParseBookDetailTableViewController *pbdtvc = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *tempObject = [totalStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        PFFile *eventImage = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookImage"];

        if(eventImage != NULL)
        {

            [eventImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error)
             {

                 UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


                 pbdtvc.bookImageDetail = thumbnailImage;

             }];

        }
```

my .h file of the secondViewController (ParseBookDetailViewController)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage* bookImageDetail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bookImageDetailView;
```

viewDidLoad of my .m file of the secondViewController (ParseBookDetailViewController)

```
NSLog(@"%@",bookImageDetail);
[bookImageDetailView setImage:bookImageDetail];
```

As I said: in the original View Controller the Image is correct. I can log it and even set it there to an ImageView. But in the second view controller there is (null).

Glad for help, thanks..

EDIT:

This is the code from my cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
PFObject *tempObject = [totalStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookTitle"];
    cell.titleTextField.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookTitle"];
    cell.bookAutor1Label.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookAutor1"];
    cell.isbnLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookISBN"];

    cell.statusLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookStatus"];
    cell.yearLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"BookDate"];


    if ([cell.statusLabel.text isEqualToString:@"nicht verfügbar"]) {
        cell.statusLabel.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.dotImageIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_red.png"];

    }else if ([cell.statusLabel.text isEqualToString:@"verfügbar"]){
        cell.statusLabel.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cell.dotImageIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_green.png"];
    }

    PFFile *eventImage = [tempObject objectForKey:@"bookImage"];

    if(eventImage != NULL)
    {

        [eventImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error)
         {

             UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

             prepareForSegueImage = thumbnailImage;

             [cell.bookImageView setImage:thumbnailImage];

         }];

    }
```

At the bottom I have set the Image (that works) in a new property (prepareForSegueImage). NOW its loaded.

And now I've tried to pass only the prepareForSegueImage to the new view controller, but it actually doesn't pass the one from the cell, it passes the last one loaded in the whole table view from the first view controller.

Comment: I have a feeling that your block method in your prepareForSegue has not finished by the time you move to the next view controller.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing:

```
[eventImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error)
{
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    pbdtvc.bookImageDetail = thumbnailImage;
}];
```

is an asynchronous request happening in the background, that will take some time to return. But your code is expecting it to happen instantly.

Load the image first and call the segue in the completion block,

**EDIT**

If it works in the first viewController (meaning you have the image) why are you requesting it again? why not simply pass the image you already have?

**EDIT 2:**

As explained in my comment, your variable is being overwritten each time the `cellForRowAtindexPath` is called. You could either wrap that code in an if statement, checking for an index or a certain image etc. or you can use the below code to get a specific cell and pull the image form that.

```
[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
```

If you have the image downloaded and have a relatively easy means of getting a reference to it you should not be downloading it again. This could cost the user on a 3G data plan as well as waste resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The reason why I am retrieving it again from parse is that I need the image from the CELL. If I try to pass the image that is loaded it actually passes it, but not the Image from the CELL. It passes the image which was last loaded in the tableView....a little bit hard to explain. I will update my question with some more code.

Comment: @tugadesperado ok so what you are trying to explain is that, you have MULTIPLE cells and you want a specific image on one of them, but the above edited code only gives you the last one. This is because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called for each row, meaning its runs through them all and your variable will be overwritten each time with the last cell. This is to be expected. I'll edit my answer with what you should do in this case

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have multiple cells. And yes I got that thing that it overrides it every time...I'll keep trying with your method

Comment: @tugadesperado any luck yet? don't forget to mark top answer and upvote if my answer solved your question. others facing the same issue will want to know what fixed it too and i'll also get the rep points for helping you out

Comment: Still trying. So you mean I should call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method in my prepareForSegue? And how should I pull the image from it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tugadesperado yes, if every row needs to pass its image through you probably should have an array of all of the images. Instead of downloading them one at a time for each cell. download them all, store in an array and pull them out as needed. failing that the code I gave you will give a `UITableViewCell` object (cast it if you have a custom class) and you can get the image using the same property you used to set it `cell.bookImageView` and then the image itself will be `cell.bookImageView.image`

Comment: Ok I'm almost there. I'm using now `UITableViewCell *cell01 = [bookListTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];` in my prepareForSegue to get the cell. OK.   In my cellForRowAtIndexPath the imageview is declared like that `[cell.bookImageView setImage:thumbnailImage];`

Is `pbdtvc.bookImageDetail = cell01.imageView.image;` now the correct way to pass the image between the views? It's actually still not working. Will keep trying with an imageArray.

Comment: @tugadesperado yes thats the right way. Update your question. Post the entire `prepareForSegue` method

Comment: @tugadesperado have you solved this, or updated the question with the new code?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are using the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock, which is an asynchronous call. As this happens in a background thread, it is probably not finished when you segue to the other viewcontroller.

You said it works fine in the first controller. I assume this means you have already downloaded the image. Put that in a property instead, and send this property to the next controller.

Comment: I actually tried that way already. But as I said to Simon I have multiple cells and I have to get the image from every specific cell.